# How to retrieve text files from Firefox cache?

Tags: firefox, caching

I am learning about service workers. It is a very interesting topic. What I could not find out, how to check what a service worker js file contains.

By Firefox you can find the active workers by `about:debugging#workers`. After that, you can dereference the URI given and hopefully, it will serve you the source code of the actual js file.

For example:

https://www.youtube.com/sw.js.

I wanted to check how Facebook solves the push notification, but dereferencing that URI does not give you much:

https://www.facebook.com/sw?s=push.

I tried to find it in Firefox cache:

`about:cache-entry?storage=memory&context=&eid=&uri=https://www.facebook.com/sw?s=push`

But it shows some binary stuff. Any idea how to extract the js file from the Firefox cache?

Comment: I found meanwhile, that `request-Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate, br`, so it is probably zipped. Still it is a pain in the ass to copy the hex code and somehow unzip it.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't appear to be just gzip, at least I coverted it to binary and tried to unzip it without luck. Maybe I was doing it wrong.